# Error in compiling using gsoap

Tags: wsdl, gsoap

I am trying to compile the files after generating from these steps:-
(1) `wsdl2h -o calc.h http://www.genivia.com/calc.wsdl`
(2) `soapcpp2 -j -CL calc.h`
(3) Creating a main.cpp with the following code:-

```
#include "calc.nsmap"      // XML namespace mapping table (only needed once at the global level)
#include "soapcalcProxy.h" // the proxy class, also #includes "soapH.h" and "soapStub.h"

int main()
{
  calcProxy calc;
  double sum;
  if (calc.add(1.23, 4.56, sum) == SOAP_OK)
    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum << std::endl;
  else
    calc.soap_stream_fault(std::cerr);
  calc.destroy(); // same as: soap_destroy(calc.soap); soap_end(calc.soap);
}
```

4. After it I compile issuing the command:- 
   g++ -o calcclient main.cpp soapcalcProxy.cpp soapC.cpp -lgsoap++

I get the following errors:-

```
/tmp/ccA5Ergj.o: In function `soap_ignore_element(soap*)':
soapC.cpp:(.text+0x112d): undefined reference to `soap_ignore'
/tmp/ccA5Ergj.o: In function `soap_putelement':
soapC.cpp:(.text+0x149b): undefined reference to `soap_element_empty'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help in compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. I was thinking the lib is in /usr/lib but it was in /usr/local/lib. I included -L/usr/local/lib while compiling, and it worked.